# boa webserver, sh script

Tags: linux, webserver, cgi, boa

I have here embedded device with linux.
There is a webserver boa. http://www.boa.org/

I am trying to start sh cgi script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html\n"
echo "Hello world !"
```

./script.cgi works, but in webbrowser I get

**502 Bad Gateway
The CGI was not CGI/1.1 compliant.**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an extra \n on your content-type line.

Also, if there is a problem with your shebang or dos-style line endings, boa will report similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `chmod`:

```
chmod 777 your_cgi_file
```

or

```
chmod 755 your_cgi_file
```